# Multilanguage .htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, multilingual

I'm looking to roll out a multi-language site and require some .htaccess work.

I want to be able to go to example.com and hit /index.php.

However I also want to mask my alternate language site to look like example.fr and hit /lang/fr/index.php, and persist this throughout the navigation of the site.

Is this possible?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using a single VirtualHost with multiple ServerAliases, you can use RewriteCond with the %{HTTP_HOST} variable to apply rewrite rules to a specific domain.

If you're already rewriting urls to provide friendlier url paths for the .com, something like the following ought to work:

```
# French rewrites
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.fr
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /lang/fr/index.php/$1 [L]

# Fallback to .com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

You'll probably need add extra RewriteCond lines to avoid rewriting requests for images/css etc.